# substr/instr calculation in Discoverer

Tags: oracle

I am creating a calculation in Discoverer 10g and only need to grab information between two points (".") An example of the string looks like this:

```
30068496.CR Order.ORDER ENTRY(1.1).Y.3
```

I only need to grab the "Y" between the last two periods.

I have come close with substr and instr functions, but have yet been able to just isolate only what I am trying to get. 
The closest I've been is using this:

```
SUBSTR(MSCG_CS_Pegging_Details.End_Demand_Item_Order_Number,
 INSTR(MSCG_CS_Pegging_Details.End_Demand_Item_Order_Number,'.',1,4)+1,
 INSTR(MSCG_CS_Pegging_Details.End_Demand_Item_Order_Number,'.',1,1)-1-
 INSTR(MSCG_CS_Pegging_Details.End_Demand_Item_Order_Number,'.',1,1))
```

Any advice?

Comment: long variable names in sample code just confuse the issue. Can't you make `ordNum`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your requirements. You can search from the end of the string - find the first dot from the end (or the last dot) and subtract 1 to get the character before that last dot, which is 'Y'. This is the easiest and probably the safest way.

```
 SELECT SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, '.', -1, 1)-1, 1) search_str
   FROM
  (
   SELECT '30068496.CR Order.ORDER ENTRY(1.1).Y.3' str FROM dual
  );
```

You can also find positions of the two last dots, for example, and get the value between them.